# Using sessions on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a client page using PHP which then goes to a Wordpress page. The session on the client page is remembered, but when I load a new page from Wordpress, the session is empty. Why does Wordpress not store my session data like my client page does?

This code is on the login page:

```
my_session_register('user_id');
$_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
header('Location: booking_user.php');
```

This code checks the session in Wordpress:

```
if (!my_session_is_registered('user_id')) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

I just don't know how to persist the session to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `session_start()` that might cause problem.

If you are going to use `$_SESSION` there must be `session_start()`

Learn more about it: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `session_start();` on every page u use session or alternatively save it in a file and include it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am answering the same as the other two answers, I will tell you why. Wordpress is *stateless* so by default you can not push data from page to page using `$_SESSION`. That is why you have to add `session_start()` on the Wordpress site. You may want to throw the `session_start()` into an `init` hook in Wordpress:

```
// You may just be able to write this
add_action( 'init', 'session_start' );
```

If the above doesn't work (I don't see why it wouldn't):

```
// You can add your own function as a wrapper
add_action( 'init', 'startCustomSession' );

function startCustomSession()
    {
        session_start();
    }
```